# How to prove a Applet is safe?

Tags: java, web, applet

I have an Applet on my website. This a very nice software, but Java shows annoying warnings when it starts. How can i prove it's safe to the visitor? Is there any free/cheap service for it?

Comment: Is the code open-source?

Answer (score 1):

The real problem, which caused these warnings are not the applets *themselves*, but numerous JVM holes and vulnerabilities that caused many exploits flying around.

You can "prove" its safety by posting your code as an open-source, but not really force that the warnings won't be shown.

Comment: The Applet code is always open source (in this case, obfuscated): isn't there a service that scan the applet code to look for malicious functions?

Comment: Yeah, but you see, that's the point of new exploits - they omit such a scans. Of course, that scanning helps finding different forms of malicious software, but it is not 100% safe. Different viruses etc. are always one step ahead, because after they are discovered, some anti-virus needs to be made, and the virus is already acting.

Comment: That is very bad :( i've past the last 2 years developing this applet... any idea on how to make things better?

Comment: C'mon, why is that so bad after all? It's just a warning ;-)